# Extract all records for current day and month for the last 5 years

Tags: apex, soql

I have a use case where I need a to extract all records of current day and month over last 10 years. For example, today is 14th June 2021, so I need all records of a particular object from

- 14-6-2021
- 14-6-2020
- 14-6-2019
- 14-6-2018 ...and so on.

The Date field that is to be used is Datetime field.

I have tried using the Calendar_MONTH & DAYS_IN_MONTH function, but I need to pass the value to these function dynamically. As of what I have tried, these function do not take reference value (such as integer ,string, date)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you read the [Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) section of the SOQL and SOSL Reference?

Comment: try to add details and do some research on your issues. This forum helps fellow programmers to solve issues and not help them to deliver their requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the SOQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c 
  WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(DateTime_Field__c) <= 2021 AND
        CALENDAR_YEAR(DateTime_Field__c) > 2011 AND
        CALENDAR_MONTH(DateTime_Field__c) = 6 AND
        DAY_IN_MONTH(DateTime_Field__c) = 14
```

Other options are available, too; see the [Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) for more information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for input. Is there a way we can pass the values 4 & 6 dynamically. I tried using a reference of Integer string and date. Do the functions work with some other data type ?

Comment: @Mitesh Yes, you can bind to any type of compatible primitive.

Comment: Hi, I tried using Date, Integer and string data type. I stored the the value say '6' in the data types, but that did not work. Is there something that I'm missing out here ?

Comment: Also, the field that I'm using is a datetime field , could that be the reason ?

Comment: @Mitesh No, it is not the reason. Let me give you an example that definitely works: `Integer thisYear = 2021;
Integer tenYearsAgo = 2011;
Integer month = 6;
Integer day = 14;
Account[] records = [
SELECT Name FROM Account 
  WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) <= :thisYear AND
        CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) > :tenYearsAgo AND
        CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) = :month AND
        DAY_IN_MONTH(CreatedDate) = :day
];`

Comment: Thanks ! That worked. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this question with `Apex`, it should be relatively straightforward. You can simply generate a `List<Date>` and populate it with the values you need, then filter on that.

```
List<Date> dates = new List<Date>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    dates.add(Date.today().addYears(-i);
List<MyObject__c> records = [
    SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c WHERE Datetime_Field__c IN :dates
];
```